# How to plot vertical lines on subplots that are generated from a function outside of the function

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

I have the following function:

```
def test():
  f, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
  x=np.array([1,2,3])
  y=np.array([1,2,3])
  for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    axes.append(ax.plot(x,y))
  return f, axs
```

**Update:**
I would like to add vertical lines for each of the 4 graphs. For example, say I want to plot a vertical line for the first subplot:

Comment: Your function should return the figure and axes with `return f, ax` so that you can alter them or pass them to other downstream functions

Comment: @Alex how exactly do i do that for more than one ax

Comment: You have a problem in your code, as you are using the variable named `ax` twice with a different meaning. Better use two different variables. E.g. `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize = (10,20)`, then `for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):`  and at the end `return fig, axs`.

Comment: it worked perfectly, could put it as a solution so i can accept and close

Comment: Not sure, but I think this question keeps changing — it's probably a better idea to make new questions when earlier ones have been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have missed something, but it's not clear what `axes.append(ax.plot(x, y))` is going to do, since you don't define `axes`. But since `axs` is already an array, and since you are mutating its contents, I don't think you need to do any appending.

Anyway, if you want to add a vertical line, you could do this outside your function like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def test():
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
    x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
        ax.plot(x, y)
    return fig, axs

fig, axs = test()

_ = axs[0, 1].axvline(2, color='red')
```

Result:

[image]

Or you could equally do `ax.axvline()` or `ax.axhline()` inside the function.